# How to use profiles in Professional edition

Tags: profile, professional-edition

I have a professional edition is there any work around for using profiles. I am well aware of using permission sets, but it only has a maximum of two licenses available.

Answer (score 2):

In Professional Edition, the profiles cannot be cloned and edited to create custom profiles with additional permissions, which I assume is what you're asking about. Account and Contact sharing rules are available in Professional Edition along with Campaigns, the latter being at an additional cost. Sharing can also be done through the Role Hierarchy; something more commonly seen since PE orgs tend to be quite small.

For more on Sharing Rule Considerations, which includes coverage of issues specific to PE Orgs, I recommend you look at this section of the [Security Implementation Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_sharing_rule_considerations.htm).